# Tcl for creating a DSL: Context-specific commands?

Tags: tcl, dsl

I was looking at using JimTcl to build a small config DSL that had a small form of scriptability. But while doing so, I noticed that, sometimes I would love to restrict certain commands to specific contexts.

Consider this NGINX-like configuration:

```
server "example.com" {
  listen 80
  aliases {
    example1.com
    example2.com
  }
  try_index [exec ls /srv/mysite/index.*]
}
```

Now, outside of `server`, it'd be nonsense to allow the user to call the `listen` command.

Does Tcl have a way to restrict commands to specific blocks like this? Thanks!

Comment: The implementation of your `server` command can add relevant commands, evaluate the block, and then delete the commands.

Comment: I don't know if JimTcl implements namespaces, but you can also use them by adding all relevant commands to one and then evaluating the block in that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mechanisms available, depending on how much separation you want. These are *namespaces* and *child interpreters*. (There are other ways too, but those can involve more work.)

With the namespaces approach, you make a namespace with the extra commands you need and use `namespace eval` under the covers. This gives you all sorts or scope to introduce extra commands and override default ones. Namespaces don't have strong separation of context; the code inside can use fully-qualified names to access commands and variables not in the namespace. (TclOO uses namespaces for its class definition DSL.)

With child interpreters, you can do *much* more extensive reprofiling (all standard commands can be removed with a bit of work; starting from safe interpreter is a bit easier), but the DSL cannot use any features of the outer context except through inter-interpreter aliases (which are almost like system calls in terms of capability separation). This is very useful when the inner DSL is running code that is trusted to a different extent than the outer code.

If you want to do really extensive reworking of the language you'll probably need to set up an [unknown handler](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/namespace.html#M22). That lets you do fairly funky things, but at a substantial performance cost.

Or you can go full DSL and feed the text of the little language into a custom parser. For example, I've seen code that uses C as a DSL, embedded within Tcl; behind the scenes, it makes functions, compiles them into into DLLs, and `load`s the result. As long as your DSL has balanced braces (virtually all do) then it will work well with Tcl in some way.

Comment: This is for standard Tcl. Jim might not support all of them.